# Can't write; duplicate key in table on schema update

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I have this code :

```
$con = $this->em->getConnection();
$query = sprintf(
   "ALTER TABLE client RENAME client_%s;
    ALTER TABLE client_deduplicate RENAME client;
    ALTER TABLE client DROP FOREIGN KEY rem_id;",
date('Ymd'),
date('Ymd')
);
$con->executeQuery($query);
```

When I tried to execute `doctrine:schema:update --force` the error is :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE client ADD CONSTRAIN  
T FK_D99D49C4CDEADB2A FOREIGN KEY (rem_id) REFERENCES rem (id)':
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1022 Can't write;duplicate key 
in table '#sql-1_54'
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

Drop your foreign key first.

Your foreign key is binded to the existing `client` table, so you can't rename it as long as the foreign key exists.